# Spring Mail Authentication Error

Tags: java, spring, email, authentication

I am using spring 3.1 in my project and in order to send email, I am using spring mail. When I am trying to send an email, I aıways get this error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client
```

My mail server does not require a username/ password and this error seems normal according to this fact. But the case is; I could not find a way to not to pass username/password in spring mail's org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl class.

My config is :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mailSession" jndi-name="${abc.app.mailSession}" cache="true"/>

    <bean id="jndiMailSender" class="com.abc.service.mail.JndiJavaMailService">
        <property name="session" ref="mailSession"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="${mail.defaultEncoding}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${abc.mail.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${abc.mail.password}"/>
        <property name="mailMasterAdress" value="${abc.mail.mailMasterAdress}"/>
    </bean>
```

Mailserver is in weblogic and it's configs are:

> mail.smtp.host=10.200.123.135 mail.transport.protocol=smtp

Any ideas?

Comment: Any suggestions on this question . Did u solve this ? If yes pls suggest me how to do this .

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools/issues/11) issue for an extension of Spring Boot

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use these properties:

```
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=587
mail.username=<gmail-username@gmail.com>
mail.password=<gmail-password>
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.from.email=<gmail-username@gmail.com>
```

By default, gmail does not allow less secure apps to get authenticated. You need to turn on the option in you gmail account to allow less secure apps to get authenticated.

Follow these steps:

```
1.Login to Gmail. 
2.Access the URL as https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps 
3.Select "Turn on"
```

Try running  your code again, it should work.

Comment: I've added the lessecuredapps and still giving the same error :S

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62604164/8874958 also helped me

Comment: In your browser make sure your gmail account should only be login and then open this  https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click on Continue

Answer (score 3):

Use below configuration:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxxx@gmail.com"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and follow below procedure:

1. Login to Gmail.
2. Access the URL as https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Select "Turn on"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Bean Cofiguration

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="<!--Gmail ID -->" />
    <property name="password" value="<!-- Gmail Password -->" />

    <!-- The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions -->
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Secondly, you need to turn on the access for less secure apps.

```
1. Login to Gmail. 
2. Access the URL as https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps 
3. Select "Turn on"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled 2 step verification in your gmail account you have to disable that first. Please follow these steps:

1. Login to Gmail.
2. Go to [Gmail security page](https://myaccount.google.com/security#signin).
3. Find 2 step verification from there. open it.
4. Select "Turn off"

Set(use) below properties:

```
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=587
mail.username=<username@gmail.com>
mail.password=<password>
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.from.email=<username@gmail.com>
```

Try now.

Answer (score 1):

First, I tried to solve this problem by changing the "less secure" option to ON on Google Account Settings under Security, but now Google hasn't supported that option anymore. To fix this, get an 'app password' by searching on the search bar on Google Account Settings. If you don't find the 'app password', enable '2-Step Verification' on your Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

It is because authentication not supported by the `smtp` . to resolve this you need to remove the username and password from the config file .

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mailSession" jndi-name="${abc.app.mailSession}" cache="true"/>

<bean id="jndiMailSender" class="com.abc.service.mail.JndiJavaMailService">
    <property name="session" ref="mailSession"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="${mail.defaultEncoding}"/>
    <property name="mailMasterAdress" value="${abc.mail.mailMasterAdress}"/>
</bean>
```

And also authentication to `false` like this,

```
<prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

```
using Spring 1.2.4
<sun-mail.version>1.5.3</sun-mail.version>
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=*****@***.co.xx
spring.mail.password=.......
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true


all this  and goto https://myaccount.google.com/security of the configured account and 
Allow less secure apps: ON
Worked for Me
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Spring 1.2.4
<sun-mail.version>1.5.3</sun-mail.version>
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=*****@***.co.xx
spring.mail.password=.......
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true


all this  and goto https://myaccount.google.com/security of the configured account and 
Allow less secure apps: ON
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.profiles.active=@active.mode@
spring.data.mongodb.database=karaoke-db
server.port=5813
base.host=@base.host@

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=yourEmail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=yourEmailPassword
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.from.email=yourEmail@gmail.com
mail.debug=true
```

**And in your EmailConfig class**

```
package com.tlcreativeltd.karaoke.config.email;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MailConfig {
    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String passwd;

    @Value("${mail.transport.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${mail.from.email}")
    private String from;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);

        mailSender.setUsername(userName);
        mailSender.setPassword(passwd);

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", protocol);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.from.email", from);
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, passwd);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        mailSender.setSession(session);

        return mailSender;
    }
}
```