# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1

Tags: java, authentication

I get the following message when trying to send email from an application. 
Though I have the `mail.jar` added for my project, it still gives me the same error. Please help.

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14
>    Please log in via your web
>   browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14  Learn more at 534
>   5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 s8sm1528084ots.38 - gsmtp
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:823)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:756)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:673)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   augCloud.SendEmailDemo$2.actionPerformed(SendEmailDemo.java:92)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Looks like a problem with authentication. Without seeing a small, concise code example, that's all we know.

Comment: Does your gmail account **Allowing less secure apps to access your account**? @see https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a great help. My code works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 46):

Do all these steps, otherwise the error will persists.

-You must have to log into just one gmail account (the one you are using to send email).

-Then go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and Turn On this feature.

-And last go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click Continue.

Comment: Thanks. The last point made it to me after struggling for two days

Comment: Thank you sirt, DispplayUnlockCaptcha solved the problem finally

Comment: I'm glad it was helpfull :)

Comment: Thanks. Last step really helped.

Comment: One can use incognito mode if multiple gmails logged in in browser

Comment: Really Thank you

Comment: Thanks it is worked for me

Comment: Last point worked for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

Acoording to [Security and privacy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en). Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps that do not use modern security standards, such as OAuth 2.0.

For javamail, the solution prevent this error is :

1. Go to the "[Less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)" section in Google Account.
2. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to `Google account` by clicking your profile picture in the top-right corner
2. Go to `Sign-in and Security_ tab`
3. Scroll down the page and check the `less secure apps: OFF button`