# Sending mails not working when deployed application to aws

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, email

When I run my application locally, everything works correct, mails are sent, but I deployed my application to `aws EC2` and I get this:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed;
```

I have less secure apps turned off on my gmail account I send emails from, the two steps verification is also turned off. As I said, everything was working before I deployed the app to aws.

Properties:

```
mail:
     host: smtp.gmail.com
     username: <my.mail>@gmail.com
     password: <my.password>
     port: 587
     protocol: smtp
     properties:
       mail.smtps.auth: true
       mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
       mail.smtp.ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

Am I missing any property or something like this?

Comment: Look at this answer. This answer may solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791972/10400410

Comment: it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like duplicate from:

[javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417636/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-534-5-7-14-https-accounts-google-co/62604164#62604164)

Comment: What error are you getting when you enable debug? Can you share your Stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved this. The problem is that google blocks `EC2` ports so what I needed to do was to turn on `2 steps verification` in my `google account` -> then create new password (option under setting 2 steps verification) -> set this password in my `.yml` file as the new one -> everything works

I also set the `SMTP` rules in my `EC2 security groups` but I am not sure if it had any impact or the steps I have descripted above are enough